# How do I set Firebase Cloud Function fieldMask?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase Cloud Function for my Realtime Database (NOT CloudStore) listens `onWrite` and provides a `change` object with `before` and `after`.

This documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.changejson) states:

> If fieldMask is set, then only fields that changed are present in before.

How do I set this `fieldMask`? And when I set this `fieldMask`, will the resulting `before` object have the JSON structure of only the changed fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that class you linked "ChangeJson" is supposed to be part of the public documentation.  When using an [onWrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-write) trigger, you actually get a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.change) object, which is different.  Pay attention to that instead, not ChangeJson.

Feel free to use the "Send feedback" link at the top right of any page of Firebase documentation indicate what your confusion was on that page.